# Flutter Unnamed Route - Checking current Page

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation

In my Flutter app, I have to check which page I am on using a widget.
I know that there have been some questions about this and the preferred answer is "`ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name`".
But I'm new to Flutter and hadn't quite understood the routing yet.
There are two possibilities here. Named and Unnamed.

Is there a possibility like "ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name" also for Unnamed-Routes, or am I misunderstanding a concept here?

The example above only works with named routing. However, Flutter itself writes on its website **"Note: Named routes are no longer recommended for most applications. For more information, see Limitations in the navigation overview page."** (https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes).
For this reason, I actually wanted to do without named routes.

-> Currently I get null for the call of `ModalRoute.of(context).settings.name`

Here is an example of the problem:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyRoutingProblemApp());
}

class MyRoutingProblemApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyRoutingProblemApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        // This seems to be "not longer recommended for most applications"
        routes: {'/test': (context) => const MyRoutedPage()},
        initialRoute: '/test');
  }
}

class MyRoutedPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyRoutedPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This print will return '/test'
    print(ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name);
    return Scaffold(
        body: ElevatedButton(
          // This seems to be the recommended way of routing
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const MyUnroutedPage())),
            child: const Text("Unrouted")));
  }
}

class MyUnroutedPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyUnroutedPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This print will return null
    print(ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.name);
    return const Scaffold(body: Placeholder());
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include sample full snippet that will reproduce the same error.